# How does doubling of life work when you are at negative life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I'm at -3 life and not dead from let's say a [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425817). If I play a [Beacon of Immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeacon%20of%20Immortality%5d), do I go to 6 life? Is it as simple as the primary school maths indicates or is there some other consideration?

Comment: Just wondering: what do you think 2 times -3 is? That is primary school math ... and the answer is -6.

Comment: haha, for some reason i thought you where x -2.

Comment: as the professor says, reading the card explains the card.

Comment: I remember this exact question being asked from a neighbouring table during 5th dawn prerelease. (Well, not exact. The player was at -10 life, not -3.)

Comment: The answer is right there in the Rulings section on the page you link. This warrants a downvote for poor research.

Comment: @jpmc26 I linked the page, not OP.

Comment: @Hackworth Any idea why the link to Platinum Angel is broken?

Comment: @Hackworth I'd generally advise against editing a link that *answers the question* into a question, as this makes the author look silly. Such a link belongs in an answer. That said, it's still a readily available link that comes up immediately via Googling.

Comment: @jpmc26 We link cards by default with our autolink tag, which links to Gatherer, the official authority on card wordings, so that everyone can immediately see what the the question is even about. Whether or not the question could be answered by that link is irrelevant. An answer still needs to provide some sort of reference, where a CR quote is preferred.

Comment: @Angew Unfortunately, the autolink tag has some known issues. The problem with Platinum Angel is that there is another card, named "Platinum Angel Vanguard", an MTGO-only card. The Gatherer website has no proper API to allow for reliably linking searches, so the search for Platinum Angel fails in this case. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**You would go to negative 6 life.**

When calculating or comparing numbers, the game uses the actual value of whatever is involved in the calculation. Usually the result of such a calculation can't be negative, but doubling a player's life is one of the few exceptions:

> 107.1b Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero. You can’t choose a negative number, deal negative damage, gain negative life, and so on. However, it’s possible for a game value, such as a creature’s power, to be less than zero. **If a calculation or comparison needs to use a negative value, it does so. If a calculation that would determine the result of an effect yields a negative number, zero is used instead, unless that effect doubles or sets to a specific value a player’s life total** or a creature’s power and/or toughness.

Comment: Indeed, the rulings on Beacon of Immortality's gatherer page says "If you double a negative life total, you do the real math. A life total of -10 becomes -20."